# Working in Mongo Shell through Ubuntu Bash installed as Windows subsystem

Tags: mongodb, bash, ubuntu, windows-10

I installed Mongo DB on my Windows 10 and then I installed Ubuntu through Microsoft Store and Ruby through Bash.

Now I'm able to run Mongo shell through Command Prompt by  typing 'mongo' command, but how can I run it through Ubuntu Bash?

If I type mongo in Bash it shows me this error -

$ mongo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Command 'mongo' not found, but can be installed with:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 sudo apt install mongodb-clients

I tried this:

/mnt/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin$ mongod.exe

and it hangs at this -

```
                                                                                                                                 2020-04-29T00:22:17.649+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
```

2020-04-29T00:22:18.079+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-29T00:22:18.082+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-29T00:22:18.083+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17440 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=MridusLaptop
2020-04-29T00:22:18.083+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-04-29T00:22:18.084+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.6
2020-04-29T00:22:18.085+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
2020-04-29T00:22:18.085+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-04-29T00:22:18.086+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise
2020-04-29T00:22:18.087+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-29T00:22:18.087+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: windows-64
2020-04-29T00:22:18.088+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-29T00:22:18.088+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-29T00:22:18.091+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-04-29T00:22:18.097+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-04-29T00:22:18.098+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3538M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-04-29T00:22:18.260+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:259927][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 3
2020-04-29T00:22:18.332+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:331697][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 3
2020-04-29T00:22:18.405+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:405499][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 2/6144 to 3/256
2020-04-29T00:22:18.523+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:523244][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 3
2020-04-29T00:22:18.634+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:634206][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 3
2020-04-29T00:22:18.694+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1588099938:694082][17440:140719013387856], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2020-04-29T00:22:19.027+0530 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2020-04-29T00:22:19.032+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
2020-04-29T00:22:19.105+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-29T00:22:19.105+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.106+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.106+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-29T00:22:19.107+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.107+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.108+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify which IP
2020-04-29T00:22:19.109+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2020-04-29T00:22:19.110+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2020-04-29T00:22:19.110+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.111+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-29T00:22:19.116+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.123+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
2020-04-29T00:22:19.123+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.124+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.129+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.742+0530 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2020-04-29T00:22:19.745+0530 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.745+0530 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: 
2020-04-29T00:22:19.745+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2020-04-29T00:22:19.746+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-04-29T00:22:20.001+0530 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version:

[image]

Please Help. I need to run mongo shell in Bash in Windows.

Comment: That output looks like it's successfully running. Are you not able to connect to it?

Comment: Yes Jordanm after i ran mongo.exe followed by connnection string from the directory, it connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongod` is the server, if you want the shell you need to be running `mongo`.

I imagine to use `mongo` from Ubuntu you will need to install it in the Linux subsystem, following some variant of [these instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks Oleg it worked after is run mongo.exe, it wouldn't except just 'mongo'